# Исходник std::vector

Tags: gcc, c++, linux

Подскажите где найти исходники класса std::vector в linux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[vector.tcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01507_source.html) и [stl_vector.h](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01440_source.html). Но вы ещё пожалеете о том, что увидели это ;)

Comment: АдЪ

Comment: Хороший пример совершенно нечитаемого кода. FAIL.